# JavaScript Random math multiplication generator

Tags: javascript, math, random, generated

I'm totally new to JavaScript and could really use some help. I have to make a program in JavaScript that randomly generates two numbers between 1 and 12 and stores them into a text field. These two numbers are global variables and are sent to a function that displays the text field string as "x times y" (x and y being the randomly generated numbers). It should also have a check answer button that uses `window.alert` to compare the answer entered to the correct answer and will be a message shown depending on the answer they give. I haven't done much on it so I apologise for the lack of code but any help would be really helpful as it's for a class assignment. Thank you!

```js
var x, y;

    function aNumber(x, y) {
        Math.floor((Math.random() * 12) + 1);
        Math.floor((Math.random() * 12) + 1);
        return x, y;
    }


    function genQuestion(x, y) {
        document.getElementById('question').value = aNumber(x) + "times" + aNumber(y);
    }
```

```html
<body>
    <h1>Learning Multiplication</h1>
    <form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="#">
        <label>What is: </label>
        <input id="question" name="question" type="text" />
        <br>
        <label>The answer is: </label>
        <input id="answer" name="answer" type="text" />
        <br>
        <label>Correct answers: </label>
        <input id="total" name="total" type="text" />
    <br>
<button class = "button" name="button" type="button" value="Check answer" onclick="genQuestion()" />
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Hint: your function `aNumber(x, y) ` returns the same values that are passed into the function. The results of `Math.floor((Math.random() * 12) + 1);` are not assigned to any variable(s). Also, I would think about the naming of that function, as it returns 2 values, not "aNumber".

Answer (score 1):

First of all you could generate a new button, which generates new values for `x` and `y`. Your function name `aFunction` is a bit meaningless and should have a name what is the function doing, like `generateNumbers`.

This function generates two new values for `x` and `y`.

Now it checks the answer an alerts a message.

```js
var x, y;
  
function generateNumbers() {
    function getRandom12() {
        return Math.floor((Math.random() * 12) + 1);
    }
    x = getRandom12();
    y = getRandom12();
}

function genQuestion() {
    generateNumbers();
    document.getElementById('question').value = x + " times " + y;
    document.getElementById('answer').value = '';
    document.getElementById('total').value = '';
}

function checkAnswer() {
     alert(
         x * y === +document.getElementById('answer').value ?
         'Great!' :
         'Not Yet!.'
     );
     document.getElementById('total').value = x * y;
}

genQuestion(); // needed for the first time, could be later an event.
```

```html
<h1>Learning Multiplication</h1>
<form name="myForm" id="myForm" action="#">
  <label>What is:</label>
  <input id="question" name="question" type="text" /><br>
  <label>The answer is:</label>
  <input id="answer" name="answer" type="text" /><br>
  <label>Correct answers:</label>
  <input id="total" name="total" type="text" /><br>
  <button class="button" name="button" type="button" onclick="genQuestion()" >Generate new Question</button>
  <button class="button" name="button" type="button" onclick="checkAnswer()" >Check answer</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you for the help! So how would I make it check the answer to be correct or incorrect considering the numbers are randomly generated? If they weren't then I'd assume you could just make `if` statements but that would be a lot of if statements...

Comment: @rozak, it is only one `if` statement. please see edit.